# Acer AO722 flickering screen

Tags: radeon

The screen on my Acer Aspire One netbook (AO722) flickers for a few minutes when Ubuntu awakens the screen after a period of inactivity. I am pretty sure this is not a hardware issue, as I never see this problem in Windows and both of my Acer netbooks exhibit the same problem. I see the flickering in all recent versions of Ubuntu -- 11.10, 11.04, and 10.10. Surprisingly I haven't been able to find a lot of information about this problem online.

I believe the video card in this netbook is Radeon 6290 paired with AMD C-60. I am using the default open source video driver.

Would appreciate any tips on how to get rid of the flicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found this on Ubuntu forum.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840439

Simply installing proprietary fglrx drivers seems to solve the problem.

It is about the same problem you have, but on a Macbook Pro 8,2 with AMD Radeon HD6470M graphics and Natty. I havent tested it myself. But I'm gonna. Have the same card on my ASUS laptop.